# Update home link in wordpress

Tags: linux, wordpress

I am using the frontier theme.

When at the home page of my wordpress site the links at the top (header i think) when i click them take me to my blog page i would like them to take me to my homepage.

I found that if i edit this line in my header.php

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/') ); ?>">
```

I can change the link the only problem is it doesnt go to the right page

IE

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url('http://mydomain.com') ); ?>">
```

goes to mydomain.com/blog/http://mydomain.com

How can i get it to go to http://mydomain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url('../') ); ?>">
```

Should work for what you need.

Comment: Thank you that worked great. Sorry to over look something so simple.